# representing two signals with different time steps in python panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have two vectors of signals represent the same period of time but with different time steps i.e the start time and the end time are the same for both signals.

```
s1 vector has 150 values
s2 vector has 800 values
```

I want s1 signals to have the same length as s2 using pandas but I get the wrong synchronization (ALl values of s1 stacked at the beginning and the rest of the vector are zeros)

```
s1Time = [.0 ,  .2 ,  .4 ,  .6 ,  .8 ,  1.0] 
s1Value = [ 0 ,  19 ,  43 ,  62 ,  75 ,  95 ]
s2Time = [.0 , .1 , .2 , .3 , .4 , .5 , .6 , .7 , .8 , .9 , 1.0] 
s2Value = [ 0 , 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 , 50 , 60 , 70 , 80 , 90 , 100 ]

s1T =  pd.Series(s1Time)
s1V =  pd.Series(s1Value)
s2T =  pd.Series(s2Time)
s2V =  pd.Series(s2Value)
newIndex = s1T.index.union(s2T.index)
s1V = s1V.reindex(newIndex).interpolate(method='index')
s2V = s2V.reindex(newIndex).interpolate(method='index')


myData = {'s2T':s2T ,'s1V': s1V , 's2V':s2V}
DF = pd.DataFrame(myData)
DF = DF[['s2T', 's1V', 's2V']]
sheet_name = 'sheet1'
DF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name,startrow=0 , startcol=0)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
```

This is the output from the above code:

[image: Current output]

What should I do to get this output:

[image: Desired output]

Another related question, how can I change the NaN values to be an interpolated value, so s1V curve is smooth.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: done! do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `s2T` as index then join:

```
s1V =  pd.Series(s1Value, index=s1Time)
s2V =  pd.Series(s2Value, index=s2Time)

df = s2V.to_frame('s2V').join(s1V.rename('s1V'))
```

You can then reset the index:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Finally interpolate:

```
df['s1V'] = df['s1V'].interpolate()
```

Comment: When I tried the code with real-world data I got a problem. The plotted interpolated curve looks very different from the original one. How can I fix this?

Comment: Interpolate has different options, check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) to see if you find one that works. Otherwise ask a new, specific question!